# How to do manual mocks in Vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, vite, vitest

I'm basically trying to mock an external module in the same way for all my vitest tests, and it's surprisingly not trivial. In Jest, I would just create a `__mocks__` folder at the root, and it appears vitest is maybe supposed to support this, but I can't get it to work. Anybody figured out this (seemingly very basic) use case?

Tried creating a `__mocks__` folder at the root, tried doing a global mock in vite.config.ts. I want to create one mock that works for all tests

Comment: Given the documentation at https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#modules, what specifically have you tried, what is not working, and what is the specific [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you can share?

Comment: Did you get anywhere? I'm also trying this and can't get it to work at all!

Comment: Looks like you can go one of two ways, according to the docs (https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock): 

1. add a `__mocks__` folder at the root, but make sure to add vi.mock('module'); in the test file 
or 2. add a test set up file whih handles your mocks and then add it to your vitest config in the "setupFiles" array https://vitest.dev/config/#setupfiles.

From the docs: 

...if you don't call vi.mock, modules are not mocked automatically. To replicate Jest's automocking behaviour, you can call vi.mock for each required module inside setupFiles.

Comment: @ChristopherBorchert why the docs do not provide an example is beyond me